# PHP mail() function succeeds but the mail is not delivered

Tags: php, email

im trying send a email in my development server(not in localhost), i do get the success message but the mail is not delivered to the desired destination. i have tried this in two different ways, but none of them is delivered to the destination

**code 1**

```
<?php
$msg="";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $from_add = "name@email.com"; 

    $to_add = "hrisgm@gmail.com";

    $subject = "Test Subject";
    $message = "Test Message";

    $headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";


    if(mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
    {
        $msg = "Mail sent OK";
    } 
    else 
    {
       $msg = "Error sending email!";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test form to email</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $msg ?>
<p>
<form action='<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

**code 2**

```
<?php
ini_set('SMTP','https://dev.test.com/'); 
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'admin@Address.com'); 

$to = 'tcd@gmal.com';
$subject = 'Example subject';
$body = 'With an example body…'; 

if(mail($to, $subject , $body)){

    echo 'Email has been sent to'.$to;

}
else {
    echo "there was an error";

}
?>
```

can anybody help me on this to deliver me the mail to the desired destination

Comment: It might be issue with smtp, I would recommend you use phpmailer class to send emails using gmail smtp

Comment: does it mean that yahoo, hotmail may work.

Comment: No, it does not mean that. Through php mailer class you can use any smtp service you want and it can send emails to all the clients.

Comment: Are you sure that tcd@gmal.com is the desired email address?

Comment: yes.. it is the email adress

Comment: mail, returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise. So true does not mean its successfully delivered.

Comment: In your **code1**, try removing `\r` in `$headers`